# Laravel Session issue

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using Laravel 5.8 and I need to store some data in session. This is the code of my controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PagesController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $this->storeInSession($request);
        dump(session()->all());
    }

    public function otherPage(Request $request)
    {
        $this->storeInSession($request);
        dump(session()->all());
    }

    protected function storeInSession(Request $request)
    {
        if(!$request->session()->exists('landingpage')){       
            $request->session()->put('landingpage', $request->route()->getName());
        }
    }
}
```

I've created the protected function `storeInSession` that stores the route name related to the page where the user landed first in the website. However, the `landingpage` variable changes every time I move between the two pages (index and otherPage) which means I'm not being able to store the right landing page and I've spotted that there is no `laravel_session` cookie in my browser.

Also, the _token keeps changing every time I move between the two pages.

However, when I submit a form (which makes a POST request), the laravel session cookie appears and everything starts to be properly stored.

I'm using `file` session driver, `life_time` is 120, `expire_on_close` is false and `encrypt` is also false.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: it seems is related to `dump()` the session. I commented that line and the session cookie appeared now and everything seems being stored

Comment: How can that happen ?

Comment: good question. I'm not sure why but I guess is probably related to reading the session before the request finishes?